# Send Emails with CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

I want to send an email with CakePHP 4.
In app_local.php i have following entry

```
    'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => 'smtp.XXX.de',
        'port' => 25,
        'username' => null,
        'password' => null,
        'client' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

If i try to send an email with following Code

```
            $mailer = new Mailer('default');
            $mailer->setFrom(['willi@test.de' => 'Willi'])
                ->setTo('wutz@test.de')
                ->setSubject('About')
                ->deliver('blablabla');
```

i got following ErrorMessage

```
Could not send email: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

Why is Cake trying to use Mailserver at localhost???
Where is my error? ;-)

Comment: Its fairly odd that your mail server would in this day and age be using port 25 and a passwordless access.

Comment: It´s an internal testsystem, just for checking if anything would work...

Comment: Do you also have an `Email` section in that file, separate from `EmailTransport`?

Comment: @Greg Schmidt
Yes, the email section is here...

`'Email' => [
        'default' => [
            'transport' => 'default',
            'from' => 'you@localhost',
            /*
             * Will by default be set to config value of App.encoding, if that exists otherwise to UTF-8.
             */
            //'charset' => 'utf-8',
            //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        ],
    ],
`

Comment: Finally i found it....
I use the cake app skeleton and i think the config for email transport is not as it should be for cake 4... In Configuration you have to tell the classname how mails should be transported.... mail / smtp / debug
In app_local i now have added 
`'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing: 'className' => 'Smtp'.

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
 'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.XXX.de',
        'port' => 25,
        'username' => null,
        'password' => null,
        'client' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.